# Is it possible to query Active Directory for a user with only the user's certificate?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I'd like to allow my users to log in if they belong to a specific Active Directory group. I don't have the user's CN or DN - just their certificate. Is it possible to get an Active Directory user using only this certificate?

I am aware that I can execute an ldap query for a user's certificate using the "userCertificate" attribute. However, I'd like to query *for the user* using this attribute. Something along the lines of:

```
    (&(objectClass=user)(userCertificate=<user's certificate>))
```

This doesn't appear to work.

An alternative approach may be to get the group I'm looking for, then get and loop through all members of the group. I would have to compare the provided cert with each AD user's cert. This approach is less than ideal as it will not be very efficient for groups with a large number of users, or users with a large number of certs.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is possible, but it's slow. Here is the syntax:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(userCertificate;binary=\12\34\56\AB\CD\..))
```

The certificate needs to be formatted in hexadecimal and must be escaped.

Reference: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.openldap.general/46598